# Identify rows in dataframe with value that exists in list column of another dataframe and is duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with ~2.5M rows. Each of these rows has a location identifier, of ~2000 locations. I want to drop duplicates, keeping the first value, of any row that has the same attributes and is within a distance of X miles of another location.

After initially filtering for duplicate values, the dataframe looks similar to the following:

```py
index  location_id    attr1    attr2
    
  1         1            A        Z
  2         1            B        Y
  3         2            A        Z
  4         3            B        Y
  5         5            A        Z
  6         5            B        Y
```

I have another dataframe that contains the the location ids and a list of locations considered "nearby" looking as such:

```py
location_id   locations
    
    1           [3,5]
    2            []
    3           [1,5]
    5           [1,3]
```

How can I filter out rows 4,5, and 6 from the dataframe without filtering rows 2 and 3, using the nearby location dataframe?

EDIT: The expected output is as follows:

```py
index  location_id    attr1    attr2
    
  1         1            A        Z
  2         1            B        Y
  3         2            A        Z
```

Comment: please provide the explicit expected output

Comment: @mozway added output above

Comment: What is the general condition/rule you want to implement, that makes you keep the 3 first rows in your example?

Comment: @BenjaminRio excluding the locations, if I dropped duplicates, keeping the first value, we would be left with rows 1&2. However, since row 3 (location 2) is not a nearby location to location 1, it would not be considered duplicate. Rows 4-6 are all duplicate on attr1&attr2 and are nearby to location 1, making them duplicates. If the index was reversed, rows 6,5, and 3 would be kept instead. As a general rule, if a row's location is nearby to a previous row's location, and matches on all attributes, it should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone trying to solve a similar issue in the future, I solved it using the following steps.

```py
grouped = duplicate_df.groupby(["attr1", "attr2"])["location_id"].apply(lambda x: x.unqiue())
grouped_df = grouped.to_frame().reset_index()
grouped_df = grouped_df[grouped_df["location_id"].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1)]
grouped_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

grouped_df["LocationList"] = grouped_df["location_id"]

gdf_exploded = grouped_df.explode["location_id"]


#nearly_location_list is the nearby locations data frame mentioned above 
def get_overlap_set(location_id, location_list):
    try:
        return list(set(location_list).intersection(set(nearly_location_list[nearly_location_list["location_id"] == loaction_id]["locations"].values[0])))+[location_id]
    except IndexError:
        return [location_id]


gdf_exploded["overlap"] = gdf_exploded.apply(lambda x: get_overlap_set(x["location_id"], x[""]), axis=1)

gdf_exploded["overlap"] = gdf_exploded["overlap"].apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
gdf_exploded.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

gdf_exploded["overlap_string"] = gdf_exploded["overlap"].apply(lambda x: ",".join(list(map(lambda y: str(y), x))))

dedupped_df = gdf_exploded.drop_duplicates(subset=["attr1", "attr2", "overlap_string"])
```

The code groups the items and then uses sets to determine the intersections where there is overlap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).